# Why is velocity normally distributed in a gas, but not energy?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

If one looks at a cubic box of gaseous atoms all initially flying in the same direction at the same speed (but flying at an angle to the walls, so as not to reflect up-and-down against the box walls forever), they will collide with the walls and each other, their previously uniform velocities becoming messed up randomly until they are distributed according to a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, which is a normal distribution. Looking at the set-up as a random-generator, this can be considered an application of the central limit theorem, which says that the mean of  a large number of random variables will end up being normally distributed.

My question: Why doesn't the same reasoning hold for energy? Aren't the energies of the atoms in such a box also random variables? However, the energies follows the Boltzmann distribution, which isn't a normal distribution.

Of course, the relationship between speed and energy prohibits both energy and speed being distributed normally, but doesn't this finding contradict the central limit theorem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The more natural relationship between the two distributions is the opposite one. The Boltzmann distribution
$$\exp(-E/kT)$$
is the more general one (connected with the microscopic definition of the temperature $T$ in any system in physics) and one may simply substitute the kinetic energy $mv^2/2$ for $E$ to get the Maxwell part of the distribution.

The non-normal distribution of the energy doesn't contradict the central limit theorem because the energy of a gas molecule after $N$ collisions isn't a simple sum of $N$ contributions to the energy. Instead, a molecule is likely to lose lots of energy in a collision if its initial energy before the collision (e.g. one accumulated from the previous collisions) was high to start with. So the previous history matters which makes the evolution of the energy non-Markovian or non-linear, if you wish.

The central limit theorem only talks about the distribution of a quantity that is a sum (or average) of many terms with a fixed distribution but this isn't the case for energy after many collisions. On the contrary, it is the case for the momentum (in non-relativistic physics, assuming elastic collisions).

It would be a clear inconsistency if e.g. kinetic energy were predicted to be normally distributed. In particular, the kinetic energy can't be negative but the normal distribution is nonzero for arbitrarily large positive and negative values of the variable.

Comment: I think that, formally, CLT works, see my answer.

Comment: Another very minor point that may be worth noting since it's basic to the CLT and you haven't spelt it out: random variables must be identically distributed AND independent, but here the particle energies sum to a constant, thus the energies are not independent random variables. However, the correlation is weak and my gut feeling is that your mechanism whereby former history bears on the energy distribution is the much stronger violation of the CLT's assumptions.

Comment: But doesn't the argument: "Likely to lose lots of energy in a collision if its initial energy before the collision [..] was high to start with" also hold for velocities? @Rod Vance The sum of energies doesn't have to be constant for a subvolume of the gas - which we can consider instead of the whole box. Actually, the random speed or energy values of the atoms ARE interdependent in the sense that one gains what the other loses - but I think this dependency gets weaker and weaker when there are very many atoms, and can be neglected.

Comment: Dear @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance, your observations aren't really central for the question why the distribution of energies isn't normal. The conclusion of CLT actually works even in many cases in which the summands have different shapes distributions as long as these shapes are sufficiently random or unbiased. And the constrain that the sum of energies of atoms is fixed is actually making the distribution more controllable and normal-like, not less.

Comment: At any rate, you are discussing a microcanonical ensemble (total energy fixed) while the canonical one (distribution for each molecule) is more natural. Fpr a large number of molecules, the differences between the distributions go to zero and the impact on the distribution for an individual molecule is negligible. One either determines the exact temperature, or the total energy - these two conditions become equivalent in the thermodynamic limit.

Comment: Hi Lubos I did say my point was a minor one and that your  account was likely to be the much more central issue. But, since the OP's question was about the CLT, I thought it might be good to be precise here. I agree that the  averaging of log of characteristic functions mechanism that drives the CLT is going to be very broadly applicable (IIRC there is even a version that deals with weak correlations), which is one reason I found the question interesting: CLT-type methods could be an elegant way to treat statistical mechanics, so, it would be really good if someone could suggest ....

Comment: ... a reference that treats statistical mechanics with these kind of methods, if one exists (this is not my field, so the literature is not wonted to me: I've read E. T. Jaynes's statistical mechanics works because I stumbled on them when thinking about the Jaynes-Cumming model).

Comment: @Nathaniel I was thinking particularly of you in the last comment - do you know of any CLT treatments of statistical mechanics?

Comment: So then why is it that if the CLT breaks down here that the velocities end up with a normal distribution? Velocity is just a simple function of energy, so the same reasoning about non-Markovian process (dependence on past history and not just present state) would seem to apply there as well. So would that make the appearance of the normal distribution in the velocity a mere coincidence with no deeper explanation?